# Creating a custom control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

Having custom control's content defined like this:

```
<DockPanel>
<ListView x:Name="TabControlMenu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" />
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" />
    </ListView.Resources>            
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}" Content="{Binding Body, ElementName=ThisControl}" />
</Border>
```

```
public partial class MyTabControl : UserControl {

    #region static properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Body",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MyTabControl ),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Items",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<object>),
        typeof(MyTabControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItem",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MyTabControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #region public properties

    public object Body {
        get { return GetValue(BodyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BodyProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Items {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public object SelectedItem {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> ListViewItems { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public MyTabControl() {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListViewItems = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>();
    }

}
```

And using it like this:

```
<Controls:MyTabControl Margin="5,0,0,0" Items="{Binding Items}">
    <Controls:MyTabControl.Body>
        <ContentControl Content=" WHAT BINDING GOES HERE???? ">
            <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">-->
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ProjectViewModel}">
                    <Partials:ProjectView DataContext="{Binding Path=.}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:TestSuiteViewModel}">
                    <Partials:TestSuiteView DataContext="{Binding Path=.}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StepViewModel}">
                    <Partials:StepView DataContext="{Binding Path=.}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Controls:MyTabControl.Body>
</Controls:MyTabControl>
```

How can I set up `ContentControl`'s `Content` binding so that it would point to something defined inside `MyTabControl`?

Probably some people will ask why am I creating custom tab control in the first place - the answer is: because I have to do something not standard - grouping tabs, coloring, dragging them around etc...

EDIT:

My goal here is for `MyTabControl` to behave like a standard WPF `TabControl` - so it's `Items` or `ItemsSource` should be bound to some collection and contents of a Tab should be bound to whatever is currently selected. To achieve that I'm binding `ListView` to `Items` collection on my control code-behind and am trying to bind `ContentPresenter`'s `DataContext` to whatever is currently selected (it is also set in code behind). Problem is that if I use `MyTabControl.Body` somewhere in the application I don't know how to bind `ContentControl.Content` property so that it would get it's data from my custom control.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to make the `UserControl`it's own `DataContext`. The problem is, you want the controls inside your `UserControl` to see the `UserControl` as their `DataContext`, but you need the `UserControl` itself to see some other `Datacontext`. You can do that by setting the `DataContext` of your root layout element, which I think is the `DockPanel`. Like this:

```
<UserControl 
   ... 
   x:Name="ThisControl 
   ... >

   <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl}">

      ...
     </ListView>
     ...
   </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325911/A-Simple-Pattern-for-Creating-Re-useable-UserContr is a proper explanation of what I was trying to say.

EDIT:
I think it might be something like this that you need, to get the `DataContext` for the `ContentPresenter`:

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl}">
...
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />

  <Border ... >
    <ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}"  ... />
  </Border>
```

Or you do it with `RelativeSource` for the `ContentPresenter` as you have already for `ItemsSource` in `ListView`:

```
<DockPanel>
<ListView ...
  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
    Path=Items}">
  ...
</ListView>

<Border ...>
  <ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
    Path=DataContext.SelectedItem}"
    ... />
</Border>
```

2nd EDIT:

It looks as though you are trying to set properties of `MyTabControl` at the XAML level, but I think you should probably be setting the DP's, that the XAML binds to. Like this? :

```
<Controls:MyTabControl 
   ...
   Body="{Binding TheBody}"
   Items="{Binding TheItems}">
   SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my intent correctly. I updated the question, so that it's (hopefully) more descriptive.

Comment: For `ItemsSource`, you set the `Source` to point to `MyTabControl`, but for the `ContentPresenter`, you don't set a `Source`, so I think it is looking for `SelectedItem` in the `DataContext` of your `MyTabControl`, which it gets by inheritance and is whatever  <Controls:MyTabControl Margin="5,0,0,0" Items="{Binding Items}"> points at.  You could try <ContentPresenter DataSource="{Binding RelativeSource=..., Path = DataContext.SelectedItem}", where the `RelativeSource` is as for `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know how to bind to `MyTabControl.DataContext` from outside - look at the second code snippet, especially the ` WHAT BINDING GOES HERE???? ` string :)

Comment: I still am not sure I understand, but I am trying.

Comment: I still am not sure I understand, but I am trying. You define the layout of `MyTabControl` in its `XAML`, and bind various control to properties defined in its code-behind. Fine. So now you need to set the DPs, when you use `MyTabControl` somewhere. Also fine, but you seem to want to define, from outside, which Item is selected. Is that right? So that you can define what the inital selection is, perhaps? And then you want your `ContentPresenter` to show a view of whatever Item happens to be selected, as selections change? I will add a second EDIT, as a guess. I hope it helps.

Comment: I want to define what `MyTabControl` will be rendering in it's body section from outside. I also want to bind these contents to whatever is selected inside my tab control :).

Comment: Yes, so you use <MyTabControl ... /> to set the DPs, and the XAML then looks at the DPs and does its stuff.